# Kentico - get inline widget content from rich text editor using c#

Tags: c#, widget, inline, kentico, rte

I created an inline widget which allow users to insert content, and it will show as an icon on live page and allow visitor to click on it as link icon:
[image]

When user double click on it in admin page:[image]

Later I need to capture the inline widget content from this page (with C# code), and show on other page, below is the piece of code I tried:
[image]

I tried using node.DocumentContent.EditableWebparts**[0]** (Yes I know this try was too random), but not workable.

I know node.DocumentContent.EditableWebparts["imcontentwebpart;c7b1d201-39d0-49c2-b3bf-9cdb74397022"] is working, but I have no idea where the GUID came from, I couldn't get it dynamically.

What I'm trying above was to get all content in the rich text editor, I'm okay with that, but its even better if I can get only the widget I wish to get.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This should be handled inside of widget source code.

System stores content editor enters as a property of the widget. So take that property and render it the way you need.